# unable to open a safari browser using selenium webdriver with python, can any one help me

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, safari

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
```

following is the error on the console :

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/safaridriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Comment: Sure thank you ! but i have tried few things by searching on stack overflow but could not solve my issue.

Comment: See my comment above... post what you found, what you tried, and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities={'browserName':'safari','version':'safariversion','platform':'MAC'})

def test_search_in_python_org(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
    driver.maximize_window()
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    elem.send_keys("pycon")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

1. start the selenim hub and node
2. execute following commands 
   `/usr/safaridriver --enable` and `/usr/safaridriver -p 0`

start the selenium node and hub